# How to use polymorphism with generics in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, types

If I have an object of type that take a generic T that extends another interface/type. How can I type an object/method param to allow any subtype generic.

An exemple will be easier to understand:

```js
type Options = {
  id: string;
};

type Task<O extends Options = Options> = {
  start: (options: O) => void;
};

const t1: Task<Options> = {
  start: ({ id }) => {
    console.log(id);
  }
};
const t2: Task<{ id: "static"; foo: true } & Options> = {
  start: ({ id, foo }) => {
    console.log(id, foo);
  }
};

const TaskManager = {
  registerTask: (task: Task) => { // maybe I miss something here, I would like to avoid Task<any>
    // use task
  }
};
TaskManager.registerTask(t1); // Ok
TaskManager.registerTask(t2); // ERROR: Argument of type 'Task<{ id: "static"; foo: true; } & Options>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Task<Options>'.
```

How can I modify **registerTask** to allow any `Task` that accept `Task<T extends Options>`

Can someone help me to fix this typing issue ?

EDIT:
Also, If TaskManager store an array of Task, how to type this array with generics ?

```
class TaskManager {
  private static tasks: Task[] = [];
  public static registerTask = <O extends Options>(task: Task<O>) => {
    TaskManager.tasks.push(task); // ERROR: Argument of type 'Task<O>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Task<Options>'
  };
}
```

I need to provide generic at class level ?

Temporary solution is to declare an array of `Task<any>`:

```
private static tasks: Task<any>[] = [];
```

to allow any subtypes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `TaskManager.registerTask()` a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) method like this:

```
const TaskManager = {
  registerTask: <O extends Options>(task: Task<O>) => {

  }
};
```

which will then cause the compiler to infer `O` when you call it:

```
TaskManager.registerTask(t1); // okay
// (property) registerTask: <Options>(task: Task<Options>) => void

TaskManager.registerTask(t2); // okay
// (property) registerTask: <{ id: "static"; foo: true; } & Options>(
//   task: Task<{ id: "static";  foo: true; } & Options>
// ) => void
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=1&pln=21&pc=56#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzlAvFA3gKCigQBMAuKNYAJwRQHMBuPAXyb1EigBUBDNAawA8MKBAAewCCmIY4iVBmxzk6AHxZcBCsB5Vg5ABRJ4KtORgBKLOoBuSEk1Z48AYwXAowAIzleA4SYK6tj4hJS6+lAGOETEUMxWmOqhhFBu6EgANhAAdJlIdAYkFkyEzCxM6ZSeAEy+fEIxJOQAROGILi0MUABmSEjk1ACu0MxQAGSwgWoaKeF6hk3EADS9-fGJyVqEVVm5+YUkq31IJVrlTq7u3A0AsjwoPHQQVLNaVBB0CJQvfvzkwlEEikMim8jUBh0Anq-hgqk2mnOFWcf3uj2eVByHy+Pyof0hXhKUAA9MSoEh+DwQHhSVEwFRjC9QFZsd9JHiGgDlEFIZybrDpmh4dYoHYSCi7g8ni8sZ82b8GpCakTaRSqTSyQZ6Yy9CAWXLcX8AUtWu0EJ1uidBlQRt0xpNuRCNakof9+Y1YqadB0uoQrZ4bRA7RMwaZVM6EWLiEA)

Comment: Thanks that I miss !

Comment: If I need to store an array of Task in TaskManager, how I can type this array with *extends Options* (see my edit in original post).

Comment: TypeScript doesn't have existential types, but usually they're not needed.  What would you actually do with an array of `Task[]` if you don't know what `O` each one has... you can't call its `start()` method.  So you might as well just take an array of `Task<never>[]` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAVjBW).  I need more of a [mcve] for how you'd use it.  But please note that this modification is a significant scope change; [followup questions should be new questions, not edits to the original](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions).

Comment: You right. I simplified my code a lot to focus only on typing issue.